# Button align to bottom, is been hidden from ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, xamarin

I want to place a button in bottom of my layout. Also i have place an image view with layout_alignParentTop, my proble is that my imageview is hide my button.
How can i solve that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnGetMoreResults"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"     
        android:text="Get more"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnGetMoreResults"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Look the picture below

[image: img]

Should i use CoordinatorLayout instead of RelativeLayout?

Comment: change this   android:layout_above="@+id/btnGetMoreResults" and its work

Comment: I could not replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ImageView, don't use

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

You must use

`android:layout_above="@+id/your_button"`

This is the final code, don't forget to modify it for your need

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in imageview

```
android:margin_bottom="50dp";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/next_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```